# Accessing TextView from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

So I created a `Navigation Drawer Activity` using Android Studio 2.1.2 by doing File-> New -> Project -> Navigation Drawer Activity.  I've got 4 layout files as

1. nav_header_main.xml
2. content_main.xml
3. app_bar_main.xml
4. activity_main.xml

`content.main.xml` has a `TextView` with an id of `helloTextView` (I have set it manually).
On the `MainActivity`, a method handles the Navigation Item Selection Event. Now my goal is to change the text of the text view of `content.main.xml` and set the text to the content of user selection. Please note the comment on the following code block--

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
            // I want to change the content of helloTextView here
            // I.E setText("You Selected Camera!")
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

How can I go about to establish this?

Comment: `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloTextview)).setText("You Selected Camera!")`?

Comment: What exactly seems to be the issue here? Just do it the regular way ^

Comment: @sonictt1 worked! I'm a novice. please post it as answer.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloTextView)).setText("You Selected Camera!");` should work.

Normally, you would declare a variable such as: `TextView myTextView;` as a class-wide variable and then in your `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` you'd put:

`myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloTextView);` (similar to what you did with `DrawerLayout`)

Then, you could just put:

`myTextView.setText("You Selected Camera!");`

Then anywhere else in your `Activity` you could just use `myTextView` instead of having to use `findViewById()` every time.

For now though, the line of code at the very top of this answer will work for you. :)